# A concern about closesocket() for experienced programmers

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

as I think I can answer this question to myself by reading the MSDN description of closesocket, I want to have it confirmed by one of the experienced guys since the MSDN kinda only implies it from what I've read.

Is `WSAENOBUFS` a symptom of missing closesocket calls to used sockets ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The occurence of `WSAENOBUFS` error messages does not necessarily mean that it is a symptom of missing closesocket calls. But it might be.

The system responds with this message if you have not the necessary resources and or there are too many open sockets. However it might also be that you close everything appropriately but you try to open too much sockets or have no resources left.

Comment: Yea I was aware of the other possible explainations, just didn't know which system error will be "thrown", so I asked the other way around.
Thanks for your answer ( and also thanks to Ates and INS )

Comment: So the answer is yes. There is a upper limit and if sockets are not closed properly you will reach it sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be a symptom of leaking of unclosed sockets.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems that this is related to the number of sockets that are (left) opened; from [here](http://www.proxyplus.cz/faq/articles/EN/art10002.htm).

Comment: That's a very old article you found there.